# Powershell: import-csv and get-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I trying to find users, storing in 'users.csv' in AD:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
import-csv "\users.csv" | ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -eq $_.id}}
```

But PS says that 'id' property not found

users.csv contents:

```
id
MacAskill Danny
Cedric Gracia
```

e.t.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the CSV file and enclose the displaynames with double quotes like so,

```
id
"MacAskill Danny"
"Cedric Gracia"
```

After that, use an itermediate variable like so,

```
Import-Csv .\users.csv | % {
    $f = $_.id; # Set the displayname into a temp variable
    get-aduser -filter { displayname -eq $f } # Use the temp variable with filter
}
```

I don't konw why an intermeidate variable is needed. There is something weird going on with passing and parsing variables with the `-filter` parameter.

Comment: what is the porpose of '%'? first day using PS and it blew up my brain...)

Comment: @nuT707, `%` is an alias for `Foreach-Object`. That is, it is just a shorter form. Just like `?` is a shortcut for `Where-Object`. More info: `get-help about_aliases`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Use Import-csv and Get-ADUser together
# Import csv that contains "sn" column and get all AD users where
# sn matches any of the values imported from csv
Import-Csv C:\temp\1.csv | select sn -ExpandProperty sn | foreach { Get-ADUser -Filter 'sn -eq $_' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it really saved me a lot of headaches. Couldn't figure out how to find the user with imported values, but just by creating a intermediate variable, I was able to get my script to work. I didn't even need to use any double quotes.

Kris